# Cannot access Amazon EC2 Windows Server 2012 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012

The instance was working fine till I messed up some firewall rules and decided to restore the rules to default. As and when I selected that option, My RDP session expired and I can not connect to the instance anymore. I tried rebooting the instance but no luck.

I can not even ping public IP of the instance, getting timeouts

Is there something I can do to get access back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. You are, to use the technical term, "boned".

The default Server 2008/2012 firewall rules disallow almost everything, including ICMP (ping) and RDP. With no way to gain access, there's no way to alter the firewall rules, and no way back in.

What you *can* do is detach the volume(s) and attach them to another instance to recover any data you might need.